# Not able to receive emails postfix Ubuntu

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-16.04

I am Unable to receive email but sending them works fine 
stuck on what to do next If anyone could point out the mistake or point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

#### Postfix main.cf file

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dlcincluded.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dlcincluded.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
myhostname = dlcincluded.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

#### tail -f /var/log/mail.log

```
Aug 12 10:17:46 dlcincluded postfix/smtpd[3925]: connect from mail-pf0-f174.google.com[209.85.192.174]
Aug 12 10:17:46 dlcincluded postfix/smtpd[3925]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8891: Connection refused
Aug 12 10:17:46 dlcincluded postfix/smtpd[3925]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-pf0-f174.google.com[209.85.192.174]: 454 4.7.1 <admin@dlcincluded.com>: Relay access denied; from=<chj1axr0@gmail.com> to=<admin@dlcincluded.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-pf0-f174.google.com>
Aug 12 10:17:46 dlcincluded postfix/smtpd[3925]: disconnect from mail-pf0-f174.google.com[209.85.192.174] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason The problem accrued is because I didn't have the domain in 
 `mydestination = localhost`. It needed to be `mydestination = dlcincluded.com, localhost`

Answer (score 1):

`check_relay_domains` has been removed in postfix for quite some time. It was replaced with [`reject_unauth_destination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_unauth_destination). Change this in your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

---

It also looks like your milter demon (OpenDKIM?) isn't running, but that's likely a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out even though That was not the problem it pointed me to the conclusion. I had overlooked the fact that in mydestination I did not have the mail domain name